# Is it possible to access Chatter influence in Apex?

Tags: chatter

[Chatter Influence](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/chatterapi/Content/connect_resources_influence.htm?SearchType=Stem) is accessible through the REST API, but not through [Chatter Connect](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/apexcode/Content/apex_classes_connect_api.htm). Is there any convenient way to access influence, or do I have to make a call out (and back in) to the Chatter REST API?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I've just been spelunking in the Connect API documentation and found the [ConnectApi.UserDetail](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/apexcode/Content/connectAPI_outputs.htm#capi_user_detail_output)  class. This has a `chatterInfluence` property of type [ConnectApi.​Global​Influence](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/apexcode/Content/connectAPI_outputs.htm#capi_Chatter_Influence_output). Which is turn has `percentile` and `rank` properties.

Is this what you wanted, or did you want the list of percentile thresholds?
E.g.

- **Top Influencer** threshold: 0.8
- **Active Influencer** threshold: 0.25
- **Observer** threshold 0.0

The following searches through the online documentation didn't find any likely candidates:

- The GlobalInfluence class was the only reference I could find to ​**'percentile'**.
- There were no applicable results for **'threshold'**
- **'Influence'** appeared in both UserDetail and GlocalInfluence in addition to the [ConnectApi.Features.chatterGlobalInfluence](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/apexcode/Content/connectAPI_outputs.htm?SearchType=Stem&Highlight=influence#capi_features_output) boolean.

Based on that I think you can conclude that the thresholds are not currently directly exposed to Apex.